# PHP - get unique values in while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I have the following code:-

```
if( $featured_query->have_posts() ): $property_increment = 0;
    while( $featured_query->have_posts() ) : $featured_query->the_post(); 

        $town = get_field('house_town');
        $a = array($town);
        $b = array_unique($a);
        sort($b);

        var_dump($b);

    $property_increment++; endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_query();
```

`var_dump(b)` shows:-

> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "Nottingham" } array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "Leicester" } array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "Leicester" } array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "Mountsorrel" } array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "Loughborough" } array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "Loughborough" }

`var_dump($town)` shows:-

> string(10) "Nottingham" string(9) "Leicester" string(9) "Leicester" string(11) "Mountsorrel" string(12) "Loughborough" string(12) "Loughborough"

`var_dump($a)` shows:-

> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "Nottingham" } array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "Leicester" } array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "Leicester" } array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "Mountsorrel" } array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "Loughborough" } array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "Loughborough" }

What I want to do is get the unique vales of `$town` and output them into a select option:-

```
 <select>
     <option value="Leicester">Leicester</option>';
     <option value="Loughborough">Loughborough</option>';
     <option value="Mountsorrel">Mountsorrel</option>';
 </select>';
```

In alpha as above, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: so what exactly is the problem? how to make a unique array, or how to use the array to produce the `<option>`s?

Comment: Have you tried $result = array_unique($town);

Comment: Use the array to produce unique options

Comment: Could you please show us a _var_dump($town)_ and a _var_dump($a)_.

Comment: Ok, I'd follow _Chris G's_ comment: **$b = array_unique($town);** produces an array with unique towns. Then use _trincot's_ snippet to produce the HTML code. (If necessary I could post the summary as an aswer).

Answer (score 0):

Your array needs to be un-nested with `array_column` before you sort it and make it unique. So after you initialised *$a*, continue like this:

```
$b = array_unique(array_column($a, 0));
sort($b);
```

and then make the HTML:

```
$html = "";
foreach($b as $town)  {
    $html .= "<option value='$town'>$town</option>";
}
echo  "<select>$html</select>";
```

If you don't have `array_column`, then you can use this replacement:

```
function array_column($arr, $column) {
    $res = array();
    foreach ($arr as $el) {
        $res[] = $el[$column];
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: This works but for some reason the values are not unique, i.e. there are two options as 'Leicester'

Comment: Ah, yes, your array is nested. I adapted my answer.

Comment: I am using PHP Version 5.3.29 so array_column is undefined function, is there an alternative?

Comment: I added a polyfill for it in my answer, i.e. a function that will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #collect all get_field('house_town') in while
 $collect[] = get_field('house_town');

 #then do the work
 $html = implode('',
           array_map(
               function($a){
                    return "<option value='{$a}'>{$a}</option>";
               },
               array_unique($collect)
             )
         );
```

Comment: This now shows 16 results when there should be 3 unique

Comment: Thanks @ob_start - the only issue now is that the values in the options are not in alphabetical order

Answer (score 0):

Here's a summary of **Chris G's comment** and **trincot's code snippet** for generating the HTML code.

Note: for testing purposes I have created the $town array manually here. Replace it by your statement **$town = get_field('house_town');**

```
<?php
$town = array(
    "Nottingham",
    "Leicester",
    "Leicester",
    "Mountsorrel",
    "Loughborough",
    "Loughborough"
);

// $town = get_field('house_town');

$html = "";
$town = array_unique($town);
sort($town);
foreach($town as $xtown) {
    $html .= "<option value='$xtown'>$xtown</option>";
}
echo  "<select>$html</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

## **Basic/ General unique usage in while/ foreach loop**

// refer to

```
$a = array($town); // $a in while/ foreach loop


if(current($a) != next($a)) {


// do your query here // get required unique here


}
```

// Note: caring and sharing